# How to set redux control on each component in growing map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Rough outline of the code.

```
reduxState.data.map((item, i) => {
  // console.log(i);
  return (
    <ChildComponent key={i} item={item} reduxControl={reduxControl} />
  );
});
```

reduxState is a growing object using fetchReduxState reducer.

```
const FETCHING_REDUXSTATE = "FETCHING_REDUXSTATE";
const updateReduxState = res => ({
  type: FETCHING_REDUXSTATE,
  payload: res
});
export const fetchReduxState = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    getReduxState().then(res => dispatch(updateReduxState(res)));
  };
};

case FETCHING_REDUXSTATE:
  return {
    ...state,
    reduxState: {
      data: [...state.reduxState.data, ...action.payload.data]
    },
    ...
  }
```

How to set a reduxControl on ChildComponent to identify each of them?

Comment: what is `redux-control`?

Comment: A props automatically identify each of growing ChildComponent.